# Problem sending IR signal on Arduino Leonardo/Uno (IRRemote library)

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-leonardo, ir, infrared

I am trying to use my Arduino Leonardo (or Uno!) as a remote with the [IRRemote library](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote). **The current setup picks up and decodes a signal perfectly, but fails to retransmit it.**

I have tested the infrared LED and it works.

I have tested the setup against a television IR receiver at very close range.

My board consists of:

[image: board schematic]

I am using the example IRRecord code (included below) with one change -- I made STATUS_PIN P3 (instead of P13), as I read that [P13 is used to transmit IR signal on the Leonardo](https://irforum.analysir.com/viewtopic.php?t=5). I made this change after testing all PWM pins (including P3) for transmitting the IR signal. I'd appreciate any help to get this working.

I have also tried this on an Arduino Uno to no effect. This is driving me a little crazy!

Code below.

```
/*
 * IRrecord: record and play back IR signals as a minimal 
 * An IR detector/demodulator must be connected to the input RECV_PIN.
 * An IR LED must be connected to the output PWM pin 3.
 * A button must be connected to the input BUTTON_PIN; this is the
 * send button.
 * A visible LED can be connected to STATUS_PIN to provide status.
 *
 * The logic is:
 * If the button is pressed, send the IR code.
 * If an IR code is received, record it.
 *
 * Version 0.11 September, 2009
 * Copyright 2009 Ken Shirriff
 * http://arcfn.com
 */

#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;
int BUTTON_PIN = 12;
int STATUS_PIN = 3;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
IRsend irsend;

decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(STATUS_PIN, OUTPUT);
}

// Storage for the recorded code
int codeType = -1; // The type of code
unsigned long codeValue; // The code value if not raw
unsigned int rawCodes[RAWBUF]; // The durations if raw
int codeLen; // The length of the code
int toggle = 0; // The RC5/6 toggle state

// Stores the code for later playback
// Most of this code is just logging
void storeCode(decode_results *results) {
  codeType = results->decode_type;
  int count = results->rawlen;
  if (codeType == UNKNOWN) {
    Serial.println("Received unknown code, saving as raw");
    codeLen = results->rawlen - 1;
    // To store raw codes:
    // Drop first value (gap)
    // Convert from ticks to microseconds
    // Tweak marks shorter, and spaces longer to cancel out IR receiver distortion
    for (int i = 1; i <= codeLen; i++) {
      if (i % 2) {
        // Mark
        rawCodes[i - 1] = results->rawbuf[i]*USECPERTICK - MARK_EXCESS;
        Serial.print(" m");
      } 
      else {
        // Space
        rawCodes[i - 1] = results->rawbuf[i]*USECPERTICK + MARK_EXCESS;
        Serial.print(" s");
      }
      Serial.print(rawCodes[i - 1], DEC);
    }
    Serial.println("");
  }
  else {
    if (codeType == NEC) {
      Serial.print("Received NEC: ");
      if (results->value == REPEAT) {
        // Don't record a NEC repeat value as that's useless.
        Serial.println("repeat; ignoring.");
        return;
      }
    } 
    else if (codeType == SONY) {
      Serial.print("Received SONY: ");
    } 
    else if (codeType == PANASONIC) {
      Serial.print("Received PANASONIC: ");
    }
    else if (codeType == JVC) {
      Serial.print("Received JVC: ");
    }
    else if (codeType == RC5) {
      Serial.print("Received RC5: ");
    } 
    else if (codeType == RC6) {
      Serial.print("Received RC6: ");
    } 
    else {
      Serial.print("Unexpected codeType ");
      Serial.print(codeType, DEC);
      Serial.println("");
    }
    Serial.println(results->value, HEX);
    codeValue = results->value;
    codeLen = results->bits;
  }
}

void sendCode(int repeat) {
  if (codeType == NEC) {
    if (repeat) {
      irsend.sendNEC(REPEAT, codeLen);
      Serial.println("Sent NEC repeat");
    } 
    else {
      irsend.sendNEC(codeValue, codeLen);
      Serial.print("Sent NEC ");
      Serial.println(codeValue, HEX);
    }
  } 
  else if (codeType == SONY) {
    irsend.sendSony(codeValue, codeLen);
    Serial.print("Sent Sony ");
    Serial.println(codeValue, HEX);
  } 
  else if (codeType == PANASONIC) {
    irsend.sendPanasonic(codeValue, codeLen);
    Serial.print("Sent Panasonic");
    Serial.println(codeValue, HEX);
  }
  else if (codeType == JVC) {
    irsend.sendPanasonic(codeValue, codeLen);
    Serial.print("Sent JVC");
    Serial.println(codeValue, HEX);
  }
  else if (codeType == RC5 || codeType == RC6) {
    if (!repeat) {
      // Flip the toggle bit for a new button press
      toggle = 1 - toggle;
    }
    // Put the toggle bit into the code to send
    codeValue = codeValue & ~(1 << (codeLen - 1));
    codeValue = codeValue | (toggle << (codeLen - 1));
    if (codeType == RC5) {
      Serial.print("Sent RC5 ");
      Serial.println(codeValue, HEX);
      irsend.sendRC5(codeValue, codeLen);
    } 
    else {
      irsend.sendRC6(codeValue, codeLen);
      Serial.print("Sent RC6 ");
      Serial.println(codeValue, HEX);
    }
  } 
  else if (codeType == UNKNOWN /* i.e. raw */) {
    // Assume 38 KHz
    irsend.sendRaw(rawCodes, codeLen, 38);
    delay(100);
    Serial.println("Sent raw");
  }
}

int lastButtonState;

void loop() {
  // If button pressed, send the code.
  int buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);
  if (lastButtonState == HIGH && buttonState == LOW) {
    Serial.println("Released");
    irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Re-enable receiver
  }

  if (buttonState) {
    Serial.println("Pressed, sending");
    digitalWrite(STATUS_PIN, HIGH);
    sendCode(lastButtonState == buttonState);
    digitalWrite(STATUS_PIN, LOW);
    delay(50); // Wait a bit between retransmissions
  } 
  else if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    digitalWrite(STATUS_PIN, HIGH);
    storeCode(&results);
    irrecv.resume(); // resume receiver
    digitalWrite(STATUS_PIN, LOW);
  }
  lastButtonState = buttonState;
}
```

Comment: if you have another arduino, then use it to confirm that the transmitted data is same as the remote control

Comment: @jstotola I am using the code above to capture the signal from the TV's remote and then retransmit it from the Arduino to the TV. The capture component works perfectly, but it is not sending a signal -- any signal at all.

Comment: I measured voltage across the IR LED while holding down the signal button + looked through a digital camera to see if the LED lights up. I also tried supplementing the IR LED with a visible-light LED.